# .NET Core 2.1 Manage Session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm new to .Net core and I'm trying to manage and access session variables outside the controller class.

The session variables are set properly and I can see them during debug, but it is lost on every request.
Kindly suggest me the solution or is there anything I went wrong.

Thanks,

Sathish

Below is the code

```
//Statup.cs : 
////Added the below two lines in the ConfigureServices() method
services.AddSession(options => {options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);});            
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

////Added the below two lines in the Configure() method
app.UseSession();
Sessions.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());

//Session.cs : Static class to handle session variables
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using System;

namespace Dsms.Website.Helper
{
    public static class Sessions
    {
       private static IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public static Guid UserId
        {
            get { return Guid.Parse(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserId")); }
            set { _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserId", value.ToString()); }
        }
    }
}

//BaseController.cs: 
////Constructor
public BaseController(IApplicationSettings applicationSettings, IServiceClient serviceClient, ICacheProvider cacheProvider, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    _applicationSettings = applicationSettings;
    _serviceClient = serviceClient;
    _cacheProvider = cacheProvider;
    _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;

    //===> On every request the session variable is null here and so it calls DB.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sessions.UserId))
    {
        GetUserDetails();
    }
}

//// Method GetUserDetails()
 public List<UserModel> GetUserDetails()
{
    ////Get user details from DB 
    //.
    //.
    //.
    //// Assign value to the session variables obtained from DB
    Sessions.UserId = user.UserId;
}
```

Comment: Dear experts I’m awaiting for your valuable suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class, Set options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;

Then the session has maintained in every request.